# GMap.net enable double click zoom

Tags: wpf, click, double, zooming, gmap.net

Im using Gmap.net for wpf c# project. i added map and i can zoom with mouse wheel. These are my loaded settings

```
GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerAndCache;

mapView.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.GoogleSatelliteMapProvider.Instance;                   // choose your provider here

mapView.ShowCenter = false;
mapView.MinZoom = 4;                                                                            // whole world zoom
mapView.MaxZoom = 20;  
mapView.Zoom = 1;      
mapView.MouseWheelZoomType = GMap.NET.MouseWheelZoomType.MousePositionWithoutCenter;                // lets the map use the mousewheel to zoom
mapView.CanDragMap = true;                                                                      // lets the user drag the map       
mapView.DragButton = MouseButton.Left;                                                          // lets the user drag the map with the left mouse button
mapView.IgnoreMarkerOnMouseWheel = true;
```

But i can't zoom to cursor point with double left click like a google map style. Is there any simple way for it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the Map **MouseDoubleClick** event and capture the clicked point coordinates and set the Map position to that point.

If the **MouseDoubleClick** event not working so try to handle the **MouseClick** event and check the Clicks property if it equals 2 center the map and zoom.

I added an extra option when you Double Click the map with Right MouseButton to zoom out by subtracting the **Zoom** value by 1

> GMapControl1.Zoom -= 1

Here's an example for the solution: (GMap.Net WinForms)

```
    Private void GMapControl1_MouseClick(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //   Capture the Double Click event when 2 clicks occured
    If (e.Clicks.Equals(2))
    {
        PointLatLng pt = GMapControl1.FromLocalToLatLng(e.X, e.Y);

        GMapControl1.Position = pt;

        If (e.Button.Equals(MouseButtons.Left))
        {
            // Zoom in with left mouse button
            GMapControl1.Zoom += 1;
        }
        ElseIf (e.Button.Equals(MouseButtons.Right))
        {
            // Zoom out with right mouse button
            GMapControl1.Zoom -= 1;
        }
    }
}
```